# Choosing hardware for Phonegap/Titanium cross platform development

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cross-platform, titanium

I'm an iOS coder and have been asked to write some cross platform code with Phonegap or Titanium. There's plenty of information out there about setting up development environments, etc... except I'm missing one crucial piece of information.

What mobile hardware should I buy? Now that's a pretty lousy stackoverflow question, so let's rephrase it to be useful.

What criteria needs to be examined in choosing an Android tablet for iOS/Android cross platform development with PhoneGap or Titanium?

The corollary question is also useful, what criteria needs to be examined in choosing iOS hardware for cross platform development with PhoneGap or Titanium?

Comment: I suspect this may be more suitable for a community wiki.

Comment: This depends on your target market. Lets suppose you plan to cover only the latest and best devices with your super shiny and bleeding edge cross-platform app, well then the answer is clear; iPhone4s, iPhone5 and some of those Samsung beasts. But then again, you may plan to build more like a bread and butter app (common for hybrid, least common denominator approaches), then you may even have to get an iPhone 3GS to be safe.

Comment: Yup, I understand iOS really well. I don't understand Android at all. I don't even know what questions to ask.

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the developers of some of your favorite apps (or Appcelerator's, or PhoneGap's QE department). Ask them what devices they use for testing. I know Appcelerator's QE department has a ton of devices, but also can cover most of the market with just a couple of them.

Comment: I'm a single person shot and don't have that budget. My iOS kit set me back a good chunk of change. I'd like to not have to double or triple or ? that expense.

Comment: That's my point, and why I'd suggest contacting people that know. Their QE departments will be most knowledgable about what devices cover what percent of the market (it's their business to know, y'know?).

Comment: Note that I already asked Appcelerator's QE department to chime in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good general approach is to pick high volume devices with an eye toward diversifying hardware- so for example if samsung has a really high res phone, don't buy another really high res phone from LG or if all the available Android phones are high res, try to sprinkle one in that has a slide out keyboard. Don't worry about trying to test everything on every device, test things that should work the same across a small number of devices and then test the things that could be very different on a larger number of devices. Depending on your app there are probably a few things that you know could behave differently on different devices- focus on this. For example, we test the camera on all devices but we would only test something like an alert message on one device.

If you are looking to build for iOS and Android I would also recommend checking out Brightcove App Cloud - http://appcloud.brightcove.com. There are good testing/debugging tools and plugins are well-documented and fully supported.